# I am confused about the data types of java.

Tags: java, initialization

Why is this right?

```
char c1 = 125;
```

And why is this wrong?

```
char c2 = c1 + 1;
```

The right way of the codes above should be:

```
char c2 = (char)(c1 + 1);
```

I am confused. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong because `char` is smaller than `int`. In `c1 + 1` the `c1` is promoted to an
`int` to be added to `1`. When you try to put it back in a `char` java complains
because it can't promise that an `int` will fit in a `char`

-edit-

In the case of `char c = 123` the `123` part is known, so java can really promise that
it will always fit in a `char`. This will work as well:

```
final char c0 = 123;
char c1 = c0 + 1;
```

and this:

```
final int i0 = 123;
char c1 = i0 + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by "`123` part is know".

Comment: Is known, Typo on my part. I mean the java compiler knows the exact value of that expression, not just that it is an int.

Comment: That is what I'm confused. If 123 is an int. It should be written as: `char c0 = (char)123`

Comment: It doesn't need to be if the java compiler can prove that it would be safe to do the assignment. It can do so for various values that can't change. For example 123. Even if 123 is an int, you can see that it's 123 and thus will fit safely into a char. Likewise with my other examples.

Comment: Another way to view this is to think of a cast not as a conversion operation, but as a promise from you towards the compiler that the conversion really does make sense.

Comment: You are welcome. If you feel that your question have been answered to satisfaction you might want to choose one of the answers and accept it.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, you need to be aware of the type of the result of a binary (+) arithmetic operator.Below are the rules

> 1.If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>   2.Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>   3.Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>   4.Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Your statement  `c1 + 1` falls into 4th rule, so the result is of type `int` and then you need to cast it `char` explicitly to assign it to `char` variable.

Comment: in
    char c1 = 125;
what does '125' treat as? an int?

Comment: in this case C1 is upcasted to Int is that what you mean.

Comment: @Danny The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It can accept a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: @vikeng21 That means the char data type internally stores Unicode value.Here 125 is Unicode value for character '}'.

Comment: @Prabhaker thanks for explaining. this was out of the blue but nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

**char c2 = c1 + 1;**

The Java language specification defines exactly how integer numbers are represented and how integer arithmetic expressions are to be evaluated.
Arithmetic expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator evaluates to int by default. **int** has bigger storage size than **short**. That is why you have to explicitly tell that you know what you are doing by using casting.